# change filename based on current filename matched with separate file content

Tags: bash, text-processing, find, for, read

In one directory, I have several PNGs and one text file. The PNGs are named after UPC barcodes, like `052100029962.png`, `052100045535.png`, etc., and I have one text file `upcs.txt` where each line contains the UPC code merged with product name, like so:

```
...
052100029962mccormickpepper
052100045535mccormickonesheet
...
```

I want to rename each `*.png*` file to its product name, without the UPC numbers, using its current filename matched to the strings in the text file---so instead of `052100029962.png` I would have `mccormickkeeper.png`. This has been surprisingly difficult; I have tried varieties of the following and with no success.

```
for f in $(find . -iname "*.png"); do
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ "$f" == *"$line"* ]]; then  ## also tried =~
            cp "$f" "$line";
        fi
    done < upcs.txt
done
```

By "varieties," I mean switching the order of operations, e.g., putting the `while` loop before the `for` loop, and even creating another text file with only product names so that I could `read` and compare them also. For the latter, I did:

```
for f in $(find . -iname "*.png"); do
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ "$f" == *"$line"* ]]; do
            while read -r line2; do
                cp "$f" "$line2";
            done < upcs_names_only.txt;
        fi;
    done < upcs.txt;
done
```

I even tried putting the 2nd `while` loop before calling the `if` loop.

Lastly, I know that even if formulated correctly, the above loops would *not* retain the `.png` extension. To deal with this, I was prepared to select the results manually and add `.png`.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me better understand the logic too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a delimiter for a file containing two fields per row. Here a `sed` inserts this delimiter and the result is given line by line to `mv`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r oldname newname; do
    [ -f "${oldname}.png" ] && echo mv -- "${oldname}.png" "${newname}.png"
done < <(sed 's/^[0-9]*/& /' upcs.txt)
```

Remove `echo` after testing. Of course I assume your first field is always a sequence of digits and the second field has no whitespaces, does not start with a digit, etc.

If you need any additional actions, like for example to check for duplicated target names, you can do it on the file at first place. Or if you need, in any case `mv` not to overwrite an existing target, use `-n` (`--no-clobber`), also `-i` (`--interactive`) would prompt for user input for the same reason.

Comment: I have assumed that you want to *rename* the files, as you say that in your question. If you want not to rename but to *copy* some files, based on the `upcs.txt` content, you can use the `cp` command in the above, and probably add a target directory also for the new files.

Comment: this works perfectly. behind the scenes, is this an instance where values are being held in an array, and then bash is cross-comparing the arrays? could you explain a little more about what's happening?

Comment: There are no arrays. Behind (or better before) the scene, there is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) which places into where you expect `file` the output of `<(command file)`. The rest is a typical while loop: `while read -r line; do ... done < file` where the default field separator (IFS) is being used, so if we write `read -r field1 field2;` it will assign to these 2 variables the 2 fields of every line for every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

In your script the $f var would be 052100029962.png which doesn't match any of the upcs.txt lines:

```
052100029962.png doesn't match *052100029962mccormickpepper*
```

Assuming the UPC numbers are always 12 chars long or that the products names don't start with a number, I'd iterate the text file lines, split the line with a regexp, search for the file name {$upc}.png and rename it to {$product_name}.png.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ([0-9]{12})(.*) ]]; then
        upc="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.png"
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.png"
        if [[ -f $upc ]]; then
            if [[ ! -f $name ]]; then
                cp "$upc" "$name"
            else
                echo "$name already exists"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < upcs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is the following.
But note this looks at
files only in the current dir and doesn't recurse into subdirectories.

```
while IFS= read -r l <&3
do
  barcode=${l%%[!0-9]*}
  value=${l#"$barcode"}
  [ -f "$barcode.png" ] && \
  printf '%s.png ' "$barcode" "$value" 
done 3< upcs.txt | xargs -rn 2 -t cp -pdf --
```